# Regex to extract emails in WebHarvy

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy, webharvy

I am trying to work up a Regex to extract email addresses off a WP directory using WebHarvy (.NET)

The emails could be in multiple formats, using dots and underscores and so I tried the following expressions

```
(\w+|\w+(\W|\.)\w+)@\w+.\w+
\w.+|\w+\S\w+@\w+\.\w+
```

Though they seem to be working in the Regexstorm tester, when I am using them in WebHarvy, they are only extracting the part preceding the `@`

Please advise

Comment: `\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that WebHarvey returns the capturing group value. Since you wrapped the user part with a capturing group (`(\w+|\w+(\W|\.)\w+)`), it returns only that part.

You may fix your regex using a *non-capturing* group (`(?:...)`) as

```
(\w+(?:\W+\w+)*@\w+\.\w+)
```

or use a more generic

```
([^\s<>'"]+@[^\s<>'"]+\.[^\s<>'"]+)
```

The `[^\s<>'"]+` will match 1+ chars other than whitespace, `<`, `>`, `'` and `"` symbols. `@` and `\.` match a `@` and a `.` respectively.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor - I used `(\S*@\w+\.\w+)` but it returned emails as `value="example@example.com`

Comment: You should define context, like this: `value="([^\s"]+@\w+\.\w+)"`. Note that `\S` = `[^\s]`, any char but whitespace, and you may further restrict it by adding chars/ranges. You might even find `([^\s<>'"]+@[^\s<>'"]+\.[^\s<>'"]+)` a better alternative.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Wiktor

Comment: `([^\s<>'"]+@[^\s<>'"]+\.[^\s<>'"]+)` this works perfectly. Sorry for the late response. Thanks